# Retaining a URL on a failed form submission in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working my way through various Rails tutorials, but all seem to recommend that a failed form submission should use a render to output the form with the errors. For example, the create method looks like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This has the desired effect, but means that if I have a new user form at http://localhost:3000/users/new and an error occurs, I get the same form with errors at http://localhost:3000/users

Is there a way to make sure I go to http://localhost:3000/users/new instead?

I thought about using a redirect instead of render 'new', but this would cause problems with displaying the form errors. Someone on the Rails IRC directed me to a way of doing clientside validations, but that seems like it dodges the issue.

Comment: I honestly don't see why this behavior is a problem.

Comment: I'm sure it's just me, but it just doesn't seem right. Unlikely and hypothetical scenario, but what if someone were to send me an e-mail saying "I get errors which I shouldn't on this page:" and then copied and pasted the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my user signup form. Since I do not use RESTful routes there, I was able to solve it with the following routes:

```
resources :users, :except => [:new, :create] do
  ...
end
get  "/signup" => "users#new"
post "/signup" => "users#create"
```

and in the new form:

```
form_for @user, :url => signup_path do ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Wondered if it was a routing issue. Will have a go with this, but it looks like it should fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Try `redirect_to :action => 'new'` instead of just rendering, this will retain the url, but the information about errors will be lost (unless you put it in `flash`).

The other option is to submit the form to the URL that is used for displaying it. At the beginning of the action you check whether there is some data you need to process. If the processing goes fine, you `redirect_to` somewhere else, otherwise you do nothing - the form gets displayed, together with all the errors. This, I suppose, is not very Railsy, but it should work as you want.

Comment: Thanks! The second option helps. I know it's not necessarily Rails-y, but it should at least deal with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being late (a mere 6 years) to the party but somehow this seems to be an issue with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks).

See these issues [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/60) and [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/251).